# Kartik GridView group : doesn't work in Mpdf

Tags: gridview, yii2, mpdf

I use the Kartik's widget to render GridView; since here all right; the group option to columns work fine. The problem comes when I want to render this GridView in PDF format, by using  Mpdf library : The result always shows classic tables without group options.   I guess ; if html result manage group columns with HTML colspan,  and Mpdf works with the same; why the hell mpdf doesn't show this groupings ??

Comment: more an mpdf related question, you might need to verify if the same HTML structure with a simple html page works outside the Yii2 ENV. and then proceed

Comment: I think the grouping in kartik's gridview is done client-side by javascript. I'm not sure if mpdf export of grid can handle that.